# Trying to show the gidview which is hide by server side command

Tags: java, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I' m trying to show the gridview visible which is hide by server side on page load method
c#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                this.BindDummyRow();
        }
    }
private void BindDummyRow()
    {
        DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
        dummy.Columns.Add("REVISION");
        dummy.Columns.Add("P_GROUP");
        dummy.Rows.Add();
        gvCustomers.DataSource = dummy;
        gvCustomers.DataBind();
       gvCustomers.Visible = false;

    }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"
    Font-Size="10pt" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "White">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="REVISION" HeaderText="REVISION" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="P_GROUP" HeaderText="P_GROUP" />                    
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Hiding above mention gridview on clicking of button  id=THistory using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#THistory").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
                $("#pdfFormInsideL1").hide();
 $("#gvCustomers").attr("visibility", "visible");
});});
```

Using above script i'm trying to make grid visible but .Gridview doesn't appear.Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: When you set a control as not visible, they are not rendered in UI. It's not in the HTML response returned by server to client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hide something on server-side then you can show it only in server-side instead of client-side.

---

Try below code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" style="display: none" ... >
```

In Javascript use:

```
function showGrid() {
    document.getElementById('<%=gvCustomers.ClientID%>').style.display = 'block';
}
```

In your button's OnClick:

```
<button ID="THistory" onclick="showGrid()" ... >
```

And remove from server-side:

```
gvCustomers.Visible = false;
```